# How to disable auto notification runtime permission for targetsdk 31?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notifications, android-13

I am using notification service and manage notification permission with switch in my application. App's target sdk is 31. With android 13 runtime notification permission appears in my app when start.

But I don't want to show this pop up and want to manage with switch. How can I disable / hide auto permission dialog ?

Comment: You would need to [request the `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` permission](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission). However, until your raise your `targetSdkVersion` to `33`, the automatic permission dialog might still appear.

Comment: @CommonsWare can I request the notification permission if target sdk is 31?

Comment: @HasIEluS: I have no idea, sorry.